# Visual Studio Code can't locate .NET SDK

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, .net-core

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS 64 bit
.NET SDK version: 6.0.301
Visual Studio Code version: 1.67.2

I've downloaded .NET Core SDK from Plasma Discover and run these commands:
`sudo snap alias dotnet-sdk.dotnet dotnet`
`sudo ln -s /snap/dotnet-sdk/current/dotnet /usr/local/bin/dotnet`

And I Always get this error:
`The .NET Core SDK cannot be located. .NET Core debugging will not be enabled. Make sure the .NET Core SDK is installed and is on the path.`

I've done some reinstalls, none of them worked. How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I have used snap to install only preview .NET versions.
I am not sure whether you have to set your DOTNET_ROOT environment variable.
I see the recommended way to install .NET6 is to use

```
sudo apt-get update; \
  sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
  sudo apt-get update && \
  sudo apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-6.0
```

You can use `dotnet --info` to see which versions are installed.
Once I installed 32-bit version and I received an error that the .NET6 version is not installed. The error was gone after I installed the 64-bit version.

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#2004
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-snap

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the flappack version of Visual Studio on Linux to work - this is the version Ubuntu installs from the software manager. I had all the issues reported by others with VS not being able to find the .NET SDK path etc. I have tried all the fixes and the ideas I could find in forums etc.

Finally, I installed the .deb direct from Microsoft https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/ This version worked the first time. The SDKs were picked up straight away and everything worked easily. I was also able to use Python without a series of workarounds for installing packages I had to do.